# Elastic Search match phrase prefix query not returning data if Value having 2 character word

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I am facing issue in elastic search to find some data with match phrase prefix query.

1. If I have value of field is `"shany shores egyptian sa 0976"`, which I am searching with.
2. If I will search this field with whole string "shany shores egyptian sa 0976" then it will not return data.
   And if I search with "shany shores egyptian" it will return same record.

```json
GET my_index/_search
{
 "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "shany shores egyptian sa 0976"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result Of It :

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

It will not return any data matching data is there to (shany shores egyptian sa 0976) But, if I will execute same query with following way :

```json
GET my_index/_search
{
 "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "shany shores egyptian"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result :

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 12,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 10.008001,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 0976",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 0976",
                    "address": {
                        "suburb": "Egyptian",
                        "state": "SA",
                        "postcode": "0976",
                        "message_copy1": "Shany Shores"
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "User"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 8745",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 8745",
                    "address": {
                        "suburb": "Egyptian",
                        "state": "SA",
                        "postcode": "8745",
                        "message_copy1": "Shany Shores"
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "User"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 2117",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 2117",
                    "address": {},
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "string"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 5200",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 5200",
                    "address": {
                        "suburb": "Egyptian",
                        "state": "SA",
                        "postcode": "5200",
                        "message_copy1": "Shany Shores"
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "User"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 5210",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 5210",
                    "address": {
                        "suburb": "Egyptian",
                        "state": "SA",
                        "postcode": "5210",
                        "message_copy1": "Shany Shores"
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "User"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 2074",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 2074",
                    "address": {
                        "suburb": "Egyptian",
                        "state": "SA",
                        "postcode": "2074",
                        "message_copy1": "Shany Shores"
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "User"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 2014",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 2014",
                    "address": {},
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "string"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 2147",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 2147",
                    "address": {},
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "string"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 5100",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 5100",
                    "address": {},
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "string"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_score": 10.008001,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Shany Shores Egyptian SA 2017",
                    "message_copy": "shany shores egyptian sa 2017",
                    "address": {
                        "suburb": "Egyptian",
                        "state": "SA",
                        "postcode": "2017",
                        "message_copy1": "Shany Shores"
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedBy": "User"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Mapping :

```
    {
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "_class" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "address" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "include_in_parent" : true,
          "properties" : {
            "message_copy1" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            
            "postcode" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "state" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "suburb" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
          }
        },
        "message_copy" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        
        "externalIds" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "lastUpdatedBy" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "mappedExternalIds" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "store" : true
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete_index",
          "search_analyzer" : "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the behaviour. Could you give more details about the mapping ? the version you are using ?

Comment: Hi @Paulo, I am using 7.9.3 version, please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: Could you provide the mapping ? by doing `GET /my_index/_mapping`